# Kendo UI style for non-widget or primitive controls

Tags: kendo-ui

Helllo All,

I am struggling hard to apply KendoUI theme colors to radiobutton and checkbox controls.

I am using out of the box KendoUI's flat theme. All the widgets on my screen are displayed  and decorated with the KendoUI theme and I get some basic styling on primitive controls like checkbox, radiobutton etc. by applying ".k-textbox" class on those. I have referred: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/appearance-styling for details.

As per HTML standards, you can't give border-color to checkbox, radiobutton elements. But somehow they are decorated and KendoUI theme color is applied to the border on mouse hover? Strange! Any clues to override hover border color on some specific scenarios.

Thanks for your help.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI doesn't include styles for radio buttons and checkboxes. The `.k-textbox` class is meant for styling textboxes (hence the name). It is not recommended to use that class for checkboxes or radio buttons because it would cause the loss of the native appearance.